# jquery-datatables: ignore 'column-reorder' event on reordering using API (colReorder.order())

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

I'm using [ColReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/) plugin. I want to perform some actions only when user drags&drops column (on [`column-reorder`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/column-reorder) event), and not when I change columns ordering via API (using [`colReorder.order()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/colReorder.order())).

I've inspected event's callback params, and they all look identical in both cases. Can I suppress the event via API? Or any other ways to distinguish the two cases?

```
versions:
"datatables": "1.10.13",
"datatables.net-colreorder": "1.3.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

You could unregister the event before calling colReorder.order() then re-register it.

```
table.off('column-reorder')
table.colReorder.order(order)
table.on('column-reorder', function(){
  // Your code
})
```

Or you could just use a boolean to test in which scenario you are:

```
var isExplicitCall = false
table.on('column-reorder', function(){
    if (!isExplicitCall){
        // Your code
    }
})
// Then call your reorder
isExplicitCall = true
table.colReorder.order(order)
isExplicitCall = false
```